# How to transition from biology (evolutionary/computational) to governance/policy?

Tags: career-path, industry, biology, social-science, interdisciplinary

I have a BSc in nature conservation with an initial major in social science and policy (focused on biodiversity and conservation). I felt unsure about whether to continue in social science or biology, so I then did an ecology and evolution minor to figure it out. I still had some doubts but I then went on to a master's in evolutionary biology, where I did some ecology and genetics lab work, and am now writing my thesis in computational evolutionary ecology (agent-based modelling).

I thought I wanted to continue to a PhD, but I am falling out of love with "doing science". I love using maths and computation in biology, but I feel isolated and like I really don't fit into the "geek" culture around me (nothing wrong with it, of course!). I'm a bit more socially inclined than most of my colleagues and I tend to get bored/distracted in low-stress environments. I'm realizing that I don't enjoy working on the same thing alone/quietly behind my computer every day, nor do I like the rote work of experimental/field biology. When I look at those further along in their scientific career, their job and daily tasks just don't seem much more enjoyable than mine right now. So while I think the topic I work on is incredibly interesting, I guess my rose-coloured academia glasses are falling off...

I think I would enjoy a more dynamic & social work environment, and I'd also love to do something more societally relevant than the very abstract work I do right now (even if it tickles my brain in a nice way). I think I could find this by going into social science (perhaps international environmental governance) as I really loved those courses in my bachelor's as well, but I don't know what the smartest way is to make that transition, or if there are any options to bring these interests together. Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: I'm not sure this is on-topic here because it isn't about an academic career. I would caution that I don't think the move you suggest will fix the problems you describe socially.

Comment: Find a job posting that looks interesting. Apply. Get hired.

Comment: I suggest leaving academia and getting a job with an NGO or GO whose mission you agree with you.